# Problemas na hora de calcular campos com javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo calcular 02 campos. O campo com o valor da mensalidade, do qual tem uma máscara. Ex.: R$ 1,60 e o campo Qtd. Usuários. Para isso, estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">Valor da Mensalidade:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Valor" id="valorMensalidade" class="form-control" onfocus="calcular()">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">Qtd. usuários:</label>
            <input type="number" name="QtdUsuarios" id="qtdUsuarios" class="form-control" onblur="calcular()">
        </div>
   </div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <label class="control-label">Valor Total:</label>
      <input type="text" name="ValorTotal" id="valorTotal" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
function calcular() {
  var valor = document.getElementById('valorMensalidade');
  var limpar = parseFloat(valor.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2);
  var qtd = document.getElementById('qtdUsuarios');
  var total = document.getElementById('valorTotal');
  if(limpar.value && qtd.value) {
     total.value = parseInt(limpar.value) * parseInt(qtd.value);
  }
}
</script>
```

O problema é que não está funcionando, ou seja, não está calculando, o campo do valorTotal fica em branco, não retorna nenhum erro.

Comment: Faz um console.log(total) e ve oque é retornado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fox.11, o teu problema está quando estás a ir buscar os valores e depois também na forma como estás a resolver a operação e mostrá-la.

Segue as alterações por mim feitas e a funcionar, tal e qual o que pretendes.

```
function calcular() {
    var valor = document.getElementById('valorMensalidade').value;
    var limpar = parseFloat(valor.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    var qtd = document.getElementById('qtdUsuarios');
    var total = document.getElementById('valorTotal');
    if (limpar && qtd.value) {
        total.value = limpar * qtd.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito Joo. Funcionou! Muito obrigado!